# Why am I not able to add a space to the end of this string in my DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

I am trying to build a calculator readout display. Must show characters appearing as the user presses buttons. 
GOAL: I want there to be a space before AND after my + sign. EX: 97 + 78 
PROBLEM: My + sign only appears with a space on the left side, but not the right side. EX: 97 +78

I am currently executing this with a function called `addToDisplay()`.  
As you can see in my code, I have tried adding the spaces in strings and tried even writing an if-statement to add a space in front if the user has not typed a number in yet.  
(Sure, I could probably just ALWAYS have a space to appear, but I don't want numbers that are part of the same int (example: 194 != 1 9 4) to have spaces between them,  
but I *would* like there to be even whitespace between the + sign and my numbers on the display. (full switch block omitted for readability) 
 
[link to full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/krmanski/dev745cq/4/)

```js
function addToDisplay (string){
  //adds the passed in string to the end of the display readout
  let display = document.querySelector("#display");
  //get the current string that is displayed with .innerText
  let currentDisplay = display.innerText;
  display.style.color = "red";
  //add the new string to the old string
  if (currentNumber == undefined){
    display.innerText = currentDisplay + "  " + string;
  } else{
  display.innerText = currentDisplay + "" + string;
    }
}

const onClick = function() {
switch (this.id){
  case "plus":
    alert("plus sign pressed");
    clearCurrentNumber();
    addToDisplay(" +_");
    
    break;

document.getElementById('plus').onclick = onClick;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when you append `" + "` to the `innerText` of a `div`, the last space is ignored. To preserve the trailing white space, use [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```css
#display{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

As a side note, the code in `addToDisplay()` can be shortened as follows:

```js
function addToDisplay (string){
  //adds the passed in string to the end of the display readout
  let display = document.querySelector("#display");
  display.style.color = "red";
  //add the new string to the old string
  display.innerText += string;
}
...

    addToDisplay(" + "); //line 190
```